# Is there a fix for BodyContentImpl jsp tag memory leak using Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, memory-leaks, jsp-tags

I have read some bug reports at apache on the inefficiencies of BodyContentImpl and how it allocates cb space. (`private char[] cb;`) If a tag writes out 50KB of HTML, the buffer size will be increased from 512 bytes to 50KB, each time an allocation is required it will create a new char[] and do **two** `System.arraycopy` calls.

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43925

This bug reports says the bug was moved to the queue for Tomcat 7 but I see nothing in the release notes as of yet.  Has anyone been able to workaround this issue using Tomcat in the meantime?

I have read about LIMIT_BUFFER=true. They say there is a performance hit when setting this flag. The code will release the current sb and reallocate a new one back at 512 bytes.

```
public void clear() throws IOException {
467           if (writer != null) {
468               throw new IOException();
469           } else {
470               nextChar = 0;
471               if (LIMIT_BUFFER && (cb.length > Constants.DEFAULT_TAG_BUFFER_SIZE)) {
472                   bufferSize = Constants.DEFAULT_TAG_BUFFER_SIZE;
473                   cb = new char[bufferSize];
474               }
475           }
476       }
```

If this code is call multiple times in the same request, this would seem to force you to start over with a small buffer and end up creating more cb's to get garbage collected.

There are proposed changes in the bug report but I am wondering if anyone has implemented something to fix this issue so it doesn't generate so many wasted strings and perform so many `System.arraycopy` calls.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, there has been no further movement on this enhancement request.

I'd go with LIMIT_BUFFER=true. As with anything where you think you might have a performance issue, run your application through a profiler so see if there really is anything to worry about. There are plenty of options. I use YourKit since they give free copies to open source developers.